# Ubuntu-Core Profile Screen

Tags: ubuntu-core

Complete profile screen:
[image: Complete profile screen]
I have partially installed Ubuntu Core and have registered my email with Ubuntu.  But now I am at a screen to complete the profile.  Searching for a solution has been fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Core installation is different from other methods of installing Ubuntu.

That is not a setup or profile screen. Your install is already complete. Your user has already been created. The newly-installed system has already booted and is running. That screen merely tells your new system's ssh login name and IP address(es).

The next step is to use that login name and IP address: SSH into your new, fully-installed Ubuntu Core system (from a different system that has your SSH key) and begin customizing it.

SSH is a required step. First login cannot be done locally as your account has an SSH key but no password. During that first login, you can optionally set a password for future local access.

- You mentioned in a comment that you do not have an SSH key uploaded to Ubuntu One. Without that SSH key, your newly-created user cannot login to Ubuntu Core at all. There is no known workaround or bypass for this requirement. It's a key element of the Ubuntu Core design.

  Folks who don't want to use SSH or don't want to upload a key might perhaps consider a different flavor of Ubuntu that better meets their needs.
- You mentioned in a comment that you added an SSH key to Ubuntu One SSO later, after the install was complete. Unfortunately, the SSH key must be in place on Ubuntu One SSO during the install process. There is currently no boot command to make Ubuntu Core refresh keys.

  Now that you have a key uploaded to Ubuntu One SSO, reinstall the Ubuntu Core system to create a user with a working SSH key.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  After entering my Ubuntu One email account I receive the following message:  "error: while creating user, cannot create user xxxx@xxxx; no ssh key found." Then it stated to finish my profile and stops at this point.  I do have acceess to login nor ssh terminal

Comment: No ssh key is uploaded to my SSO account.

Comment: Hello again,  I generated an ssh using putty and placed this in the SSO account.  I am trying to get the key to work and do not want to work around it.  I also tried generating a key on the remote Ubuntu box and uploaded this to SSO; this did not work either.  Additionally, when trying to log in remotely using putty it does as for password and I enter the password for the ssh key.  Still does not work.

Comment: Edited to address comments. FYI: There are some great step-by-step tutorials at https://ubuntu.com/core/docs that might save you some frustration.

Comment: I have read the tutorials at length, but they all have their own method of implementing the SSH keys to the client. Here's the latest:  ssh-copy-id ubuntu.lan@192.168.105
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.105 port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: The image you provided in your Question says that the Ubuntu Core IP address is not 192.168.1.105, and the username is not ubuntu.lan. Does this mean that you successfully connected to your Ubuntu Core system using SSH? You cannot copy a new key to the Ubuntu Core system until you can connect to it.

Comment: Port 22 enabled.  But before entering my Ubuntu email address., I try to connect to the client and upload the SSH key.  ubuntu.lan@192.168.1.28
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
ubuntu.lan@192.168.1.28's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
ubuntu.lan@192.168.1.28's password: 
ubuntu.lan@192.168.1.28: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, that seems to look like expected behavior. From your description, seems that the Ubuntu Core system has not created your account yet. You have not yet told it your username, and it has not yet downloaded that username's key from Ubuntu One SSO.

Comment: I am very grateful for all your help; you keep pointing me in the correct direction.  I created the Ubuntu One account yesterday, perhaps I need to wait long for their server to update; I have no idea.  The problem is that my password assigned to the SSH key keeps getting rejected.  I have checked ownership of the keys and all is fine. Here's the latest: ssh -i id_rsa.pub km7kk@192.168.1.28
km7kk@192.168.1.28's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: ssh-keygen -y
Enter file in which the key is (/home/jro/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase: 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQDLF9NeSBJdap/oczQUF+e9OO5GI66Zk5Jnh6vjnyM4EPgCPH6IRLUp0zEEEtD4NrARFXwap1i5H9Qq5+z3n0ArHc/kWseRTxCxLf10q9C1HLJycEPOOQaSjgnVYF1iaZnS3k3Ii5LRgVYuHHkMHTzCHKmdta1mWh4K20/BDQ7Qfyrs+e1tuenwPVAtoKN8jRyOx/31ga3ZTK/hbRZfzHRT+4HKiUaBHjb04aB1QeaqVK8D29V7nA5slBazCZZneHa2rHKvzuTHpReBoSalOqE7crE0d4ay8SYZyfDqvoZVxrF89S39LO5Z9+R9RMWvHMvzlwRLIHn9Ry1cuPalEroTeBTcFrphok1ttoDKB8IA1dGggMJ3Ws5sCaxTNxwFe8xtKQzbdaBGBM5O+3nbSBMKNNJGYPhFsQYH10Y5RiHbLgRSPPDPDPFRBNcO2QvtchgE= jro@MSI1-Ubuntu

Comment: ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.23 port 22: No route to host